# nsight-compute does nothing upon invocation

Tags: cuda, nsight-compute

I run:

```
joeuser@myhost$ su
joeuser@myhost# /opt/nvidia/nsight-compute/ncu-ui
joeuser@myhost#
```

... and nothing comes up. Why?

(The `su` is due to permission issues, it's not what this bug is about.)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible (likely?) that another instance of nsight-compute, from a previous invocation of yours, is still running. Try: `pgrep ncu` or `ps aux | grep ncu`. If you find a running instance (that's not the `grep ncu` process mind you) - kill it. But make sure it isn't some other person running it!

Then `ncu-ui` should start properly.